# How can I use my HiddenField value as a tooltip?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` with `ItemTemplate`s. `HiddenField`s are inside the `GridView` and bound to a database field. I want to select the `HiddenField` value as tooltip. I am using qTip for the tooltip.

```
<GridView ID="GridView1"...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label                                      
        <asp:HiddenField ID="IDVal" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
```

JQuery:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").qtip({
             content:
                // How can I access the hidden field value
                // for each GridView row?
                ,
             style: {
                 name: 'blue',
                 tip: 'leftMiddle'
             },
             position: {
                 corner: {
                     target: 'rightMiddle',
                     tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
                 }
             }
         });
     });
</script>
```

My question is, how can I access `HiddenField` values for each `GridView` row and display that `HiddenField`'s value as Tooltip text.

The JQuery part is given below :

```
content:
    // How can I access the hidden field value
    // for each GridView row?
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you bind the content to the title property.If you can do that you can use this [Beauty tip](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) jquery plugin

you can use contentSelector property to specify the source of the tooltip text as well if don't want to bind content to title property

Comment: thanks,I am already using Qtip,I have issue with selecting hiddenfields through jQuery